# Returned Error 400 Request failed Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, urlfetch

I have this code that I use to create PDF from spreadsheets and I modified it to use it in another spreadsheet and now I'm getting this error.

Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: <meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

The full error seems to be:

Page Not Found/* Copyright 2022 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved. */

.goog-inline-block{position:relative;display:-moz-inline-box;display:inline-block}* html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}*:first-child+html .goog-inline-block{display:inline}#drive-logo{margin:18px 0;position:absolute;white-space:nowrap}.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png');background-size:116px 41px;display:inline-block;height:41px;vertical-align:bottom;width:116px}.docs-drivelogo-text{color:#000;display:inline-block;opacity:0.54;text-decoration:none;font-family:'Product Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:32px;text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;position:relative;top:-6px;left:-7px;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),(min-resolution:144dpi){.docs-drivelogo-img{background-image:url('//ssl.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_116x41dp.png')}}body {background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}a, a:link, a:visited {color: #112ABB;}.errorMessage {font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%;}Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.

Please check the address and try again.

**Get stuff done with Google Drive**

Apps in Google Drive make it easy to create, store and share online documents, spreadsheets, presentations and more.

Learn more at [drive.google.com/start/apps](https://drive.google.com/start/apps).

html {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}body {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}#outerContainer {margin: auto; max-width: 750px;}#innerContainer {margin-bottom: 20px; margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top: 80px; position: relative;}

Is there a way I can solve this error?
Here's the script:

````
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cEFEmTuVisjOvOpN1JieOOIvJloYcgFHQmD5a07lnCo/edit#gid=1149589669');   
  var sheetName = ss2.getSheetByName('Exportación_pdf');
  var sheetName2 = ss2.getSheetByName('Selección pedido');
  var folderID = "14QBHZ5268OI9cqurbcIuvDfa3GG6HUVa"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var num_rows = sheetName.getRange("AR1").getValue();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); 
  var pdfName = ss2.getSheetByName('Exportación_pdf').getRange('F1:F3').getValue() + "_" + ss2.getSheetByName('Exportación_pdf').getRange('AK5').getValue() + "_" + ss2.getSheetByName('Selección pedido').getRange('Q4').getValue(); // Nombre del documento
  var bogus = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Creando PDF');

  // export url
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ss2.getId()+'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&range=Exportacion_pdf!AJ1:AQ'+num_rows
  + '&size=A4'                           // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=false'                     // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true'                        // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=true&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=true'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&top_margin=0.5&bottom_margin=0.5&left_margin=0.5&right_margin=0.5'
  + '&gid='+ss2.getSheetId();    // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName+'.pdf');

  // delete pdf if already exists
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(pdfName);
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }

  // create pdf
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  return true;

 }```

Thank you so much in advance!
````

Comment: What do you mean with `muteHttpExceptions` not working? You have to add it to the options of your `UrlFetchApp`, can you provide the full error with `muteHttpExceptions: true`?

Comment: done! turns out i was doing it wrong, I added the full error to the question now, sorry!

Comment: Try to change the `sheetName` to `sheetName.getId()`

Comment: I then get a typeerror saying sheetName.getId() is not a function

Comment: Sorry, `sheetName` to `ss2.getId()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```js
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+sheetName+'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
```

To this:

```js
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+ss2.getId()+'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
```

Seems you are not adding the Google Sheet `id` to the URL.

Comment: this is what I did before but in that case I get a pdf of a sheet that is not the one i want the pdf of, which is "Exportación_pdf", that is why I changed it to sheetName, because that is the right sheet

Comment: So in this case add the desired range `+ '&range=Exportacion_pdf!AJ1:AQ'+num_rows`

Comment: I now get error 400, I'll add the full error to the question

Comment: Please, in the gid, add the Google Sheet ID you want to export, not `ss2.getId()`, that refers to the whole Spreadsheet. And in the range, leave it as it is in the beginning ` + '&range=AJ1:AQ'+num_rows`

Comment: Thank you! it works now! I left it as it was and changed the sheet that I wanted to export to the first sheet of the spreadsheet and now it works!